# <JSP> How to code a simple sorting function

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Hi I have a list of year displayed as following.

```
YEAR
====

2014
2013
2012
```

And following is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


});
</script>
....
<form id="frm" name="frm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="year" name="year" />
...
<tr>
   <th> YEAR 
         <a href="">▼</a>
         <a href="">▲</a>
  </th>
<tr>
...
<c:forEach items="${resultList}" var="result">
<tr>
    <td>${result.year}</td>
</tr>
```

So when I click on the ▼, it should sort the list descending. And clicking ▲, it should do ascending.

Can someone help coding this?

Comment: You have a stub function of JavaScript/jQuery. Do you intend to do the sorting there? If so, tag the question with the `javascript` and `jquery` tags.

Answer (score 0):

If your year values are in a JavaScript array, you can just use Array.sort().  In your case it would be something like

```
years = [2013, 2012, 2014];
years.sort();
```

To sort in reverse order you can define your own compare function like this:

```
years.sort(function(a, b) { return b - a; });
```

See the MDN documentation for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort